# Can't see ionic styles in angular 17 standalone app

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, angular17, angular-standalone-components

I have an angular 17 standalone app in witch i added ionic for use certain components like IonSearchbar (this is a requisite in my case). The ionic component works fine, but it has no stysles.

my angular.json has the automatic styles added qehen I added ionic:

```
"styles": [
  "src/styles.scss",
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/core.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/normalize.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/structure.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/typography.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/display.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/padding.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/float-elements.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/text-alignment.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/text-transformation.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/flex-utils.css"
  },
  {
    "input": "src/theme/variables.css"
  }
],
```

I try adding this on index.html with no results:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link href="node_modules/@ionic/angular/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@7.1.0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
```

Here is my standalone component example:

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { IonSearchbar } from '@ionic/angular/standalone';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterModule, TranslateModule, IonSearchbar],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSearchChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event.detail.value);
  }
}
```

and the template is this:

```
<ion-searchbar (ionChange)="onSearchChange($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

So it search fine, but I cant see the styles working, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Ok finaly I get it. The problem is in the index.html the imports must be like that:

```
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/ionic.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ionic/core/css/ionic.bundle.css" />
```